# using pandas str.find method to slice strings in dataframe column

Tags: python, pandas, indexing, slice

I have a dataframe column which could look something like this:

```
s = pd.Series(["a0a1a3", "b1b3", "c1c1c3c3"], index=["A", "B", "C"])
```

I can find the str.find method to find at each cell the indeces I want:

```
s.str.find('1').values
array([3, 1, 1])
s.str.find('3').values
array([5, 3, 5])
```

However I cannot find how to use these function to cut a strings in that column. For example:

```
s.str[s.str.find('1').values:s.str.find('3').values].values
```

gives

```
array([ nan,  nan,  nan])
```

Which is the right way to combine these functions?

Comment: please post your desired data set - it's not quite clear what do you want to achieve

Comment: Please read [how to make good reproducible pandas examples](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20109391/how-to-make-good-reproducible-pandas-examples) and edit your post correspondingly.

Comment: pandas is very very poorly implemented in its intuitiveness

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Is that what you want?

```
In [87]: s.str.split('1').str[0]
Out[87]:
A    a
B    b
C    c
dtype: object

In [88]: s.str.split('1').str[1]
Out[88]:
A    a2
B    b2
C    c2
dtype: object
```

or

```
In [89]: s.str.split('1', expand=True)
Out[89]:
   0   1
A  a  a2
B  b  b2
C  c  c2
```

You will find a lot of useful examples on the [official Pandas docs site](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/text.html)

**UPDATE:**

```
In [203]: s = pd.Series(["a1a2", "b1b2", "c1c2", "aaaaaa1XX"], index=["A", "B", "C", "D"])

In [204]: s
Out[204]:
A         a1a2
B         b1b2
C         c1c2
D    aaaaaa1XX
dtype: object

In [205]: s.str.split('1', expand=True)
Out[205]:
        0   1
A       a  a2
B       b  b2
C       c  c2
D  aaaaaa  XX
```

**UPDATE2:**

```
In [224]: s
Out[224]:
A      a0a1a3
B        b1b3
C    c1c1c3c3
dtype: object

In [225]: s.str.extract(r'1(.*?)3', expand=False)
Out[225]:
A      a
B      b
C    c1c
dtype: object
```

NOTE: please always post **both** source and desired data sets - otherwise we have to guess what are you trying to achieve...

Comment: Thank you very much for the reply but it is not exactly that: In this case you know the "1" string is in the same index for all the cells. How would you do it if it wasn't?

Comment: @Delosari, it will work as well - see updated answer ;-)

Comment: thanks again. I can manage to work with what you have given me but I wonder if there is another way: In your method you are cutting the column series each time to get the parts you want. But myself I wanted to work with the ".find" method to find the indeces I need to slice the strings. Is there not way to use the indeces from ".find" in a ".str[idxInidial:idxFinal]" structure

Comment: @Delosari, most probably it's possible, but it's not idiomatic way to do that and it will look ugly. Third rule of Python Zen says - `"Simple is better than complex."`

Comment: I have updated the question for a better description